# Exporting NFS volume to public IP

Tags: nfs, ip-address

I need to have access to a shared volume from my server.
I talked with my sysadmins and I knew that this volume could not be exported to a private IP address due to technical reasons. 
My server and the volume stays in the same datacenter.
They need to use my server public IP.

Are there some drawbacks with this approach?
Should I be worry about the shared volume?

Cheers

FB

Comment: from what I know, if you shared volume is exported using nfs, in a normal world, nfs isn't exposed to public, but only on the private network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have appropriately firewalled the NFS server, closely monitor it and you should be fine.

This has other drawbacks of course, aside from the security implications.

Comment: What kind of implications?

Comment: Everything on a public interface is at risk and must be proteced and monitored, which might not be necessary on a private interface. I call this a security implication...

Comment: Oh, sure. I though you were thinking about something else.